# Aprender a escribir funciones JavaScript

Tags: javascript, funciones

Soy nueva en esto, y estoy aprendiendo a escribir funciones en *JavaScript*, pero siempre algo hago mal y no entiendo muy bien aun. Si alguien pudiera ayudarme seria de gran utilidad.

Dejo lo escrito que vi en un ejercicio en youtube y que me sale mal, me da solo un resultado y debería de darme tres al unísono.

```js
var 
a=1 
b=4 
c=5 
d=6 
e=3 
f=5
sumarnumeros(a,b);
sumarnumeros(c,d);
sumarnumeros(e,f);
function sumarnumeros(numero1 , numero2)
{
    var sumatotal = numero1 + numero2;
    return sumatotal;
}
```

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con que debería darte tres? La función tiene un `return`, pero en las llamadas no asignas nada ni muestras nada.

Comment: Pues yo agregué cada llamado de la función en un console.log y funciona perfecto

Comment: hola gracias por tu ayuda, recien estoy aprendiendo las funciones y no sabia si llamar a la funcion con un console.log o return, pero mi consulta es si ese llamado se hace tres veces?

Comment: Llamas a la función tres veces y ocurre tres veces el código de la función, pero no lo ves porque no muestras nada ni asignas nada. Si pones un `console.log` o un `alert` o lo que sea, verás que ocurre tres veces. OJO: generalmente `console.log` es para depurar, generalmente, las funciones son para hacer cosas, y cuando le pones un `return` es porque necesitas el resultado de la función para seguir usándolo una vez la función haya hecho su trabajo.

Comment: @EstefaniaD te recomiendo investigues sobre `return` y `console.log` y donde se aplican y para que existen

Comment: muchas gracias por su ayuda, investigare mas acerca de estos y poder resolver los ejercicios de funciones!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para hacer prueba (depuración), puedes poner de forma temporal un `console.log` o un `alert` dentro de la función, así verás que el código ocurrirá cada vez que llames a la función.

Por ejemplo:

```
function sumarnumeros(numero1 , numero2)
{
    var sumatotal = numero1 + numero2;
    console.log(sumatotal);
    return sumatotal;
}
```

Si usas `console.log`, tienes que activar la consola del navegador para ver el texto.

O bien:

```
function sumarnumeros(numero1 , numero2)
{
    var sumatotal = numero1 + numero2;
    alert(sumatotal);
    return sumatotal;
}
```

Como ya dije, generalmente esto sólo se coloca en etapa de desarrollo, para depurar el código, luego deberías quitar los `console.log`.

Generalmente, las funciones con `return` se usan para recuperar el valor obtenido de la función y usarlo a posteriori, por eso generalmente se asigna o se usa lo que estas devuelven con algo así:

```
var mSuma=sumarnumeros(a,b);
//Usar mSuma;
```

O algo así:

```
console.log(sumarnumeros(c,d));
```

O bien:

```
alert(sumarnumeros(e,f));
```

Para más detalles puedes consultar [la documentación en MDN sobre funciones](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Funciones).

Comment: use el console.log("sumarnumeros:" +sumatotal); y eso me dio el resultado de las tres variables de sumar numeros. De cualquier manera, tendre que revisar cual es la diefrencia entre return y console.log, para saber cuando utilizar cada uno, que es algo que aun no me queda claro.

Comment: @EstefaniaD `return`, como su nombre lo indica, retorna el control del código al punto en el cual fue llamada la función, devolviendo lo que hayas puesto, de modo que `return sumatotal;` devuelve el valor que tenga `sumatotal` en ese momento. Mientras que `console.log` lo que hace es imprimir en la consola lo que le hayas indicado entre paréntesis. Lo del `return` está explicado en el enlace al final de la respuesta y para `console.log`, [puedes verlo aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Console/log). Cuando pones `return` en una función, no se ejecutan nada más dentro de ella.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda! muy util informacion!

Answer (score 1):

Tambien puedes imprimir el resultado, claro que se repetira dos veces en la alerta y tambien lo tendras en texto:

imprimir("La suma de los numeros es: " + sumarnumeros(a,b) + " , " + sumarnumeros(c,d) + " y " + sumarnumeros(e,f));

espero y te pueda servir de ayuda (yo tambien estoy recien aprendiendo solo)

Comment: Gracias por tu colaboración, pero tu respuesta podría mejorarse, recuerda que la mayor parte de usuarios que preguntan están aprendiendo y varios no comprenderán cuando agregas **`imprimir(...`**, ¿qué se supone que hace *imprimir*?, tal vez poner **`console.log(...`** o **`alert(...`** seria lo mejor para dar un ejemplo, de todas formas me parece que el usuario **A. Cedano** ya respondió correctamente incluyendo lo que pusiste como respuesta. ;)

Answer (score 0):

por lo que veo si esta retornando la operación pero no imprime el valor. Si mandas a llamar la función adentro de un console.log te debería dar el resultado sin ningún problema.

```
console.log(sumarnumeros(1,5));
```

Comment: Tendrías que llamar la función 3 veces dentro de un console.log